# APC220 and the not so magical RF-Magic

Tags: programmer

I have purchased a pair of [APC220](http://www.dfrobot.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=45_81&product_id=57) modules.
I also purchased a USB TTL module to program these.
I down loaded the drivers from Silabs and the RF-magic 4.2 software which is supposed to be able to program thee modules.
The RF-Magic program is proving less than magical as it does not see the device.
Tried 3 different computers
While trolling the web for suggestions option I came across the APC220 software which finds my device but does not allow me to change the settings that I need to change as it is for a different type of device using the same chip. 
I tried a FTDI cable but this does not help.
Any suggestions?
Warren

Comment: Friend, I managed after several attempts! You have to configure the adapter to COM1 port, and then with open source software, you connect the transceiver.

Comment: list/ compare driver versions http://wiki.openpilot.org/download/attachments/18120867/CP210x_VCP_Win2K_XP_S2K3.exe?version=1&modificationDate=1313768610000     http://www.silabs.com/products/mcu/Pages/USBtoUARTBridgeVCPDrivers.aspx   http://wiki.openpilot.org/download/attachments/18120867/CP210x_VCP_Win2K_XP_S2K3.exe?version=1&modificationDate=1313768610000  and ensure COM ports are setup correct.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to have to say this, but I also had the same issues to the point of frustration. Unfortunately they were a complete failure to me. Much better off with XBees, which worked almost instantly.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same frustrations with RF-magic V4.2 communicating with APC200A-43A (also sold as CM-12111. I finally got it to work by starting RF magic, connecting the APC200A, then applying power to the APC200A. I think the APC200A has a power-on start up routine that senses the "55AA" sequence being sent by RF-Magic and dynamically adapts to the 119k baud rate RF-Magic uses.

Answer (score 1):

I also had issues with FTDI, but was able to fix it by changing the driver settings from Device Manager (win XP):
- select the Ports (COM/LPT) / USB Serial Port (COMx) / Properties
- Port SettingsTab/ Advanced
- Change USB Transmit sizes (both TX and RX) to 128
- BM options, Latency timer to 2ms.

Also other values probably work, I only tried these and it was all good!

I had to first connect the data lines and ground, then put in the VCC to power the module, and RF-Magic sees it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Find the RF-Magic executable: i.e. APC22X_V12A.exe:

- Right-click and goto "properties".
- Goto the compatibility tab.
- Set the checkbox "Run this program as Administrator".

Now run RF-Magic, you will have to confirm the program is safe to run.  If it works the "PC Series" option will show COM1, and in the bottom of the window it will say "COM1 Opened".

Answer (score 1):

Basing on datasheet I wrote a small script that reconfigures APC-2x0 transceivers (and also works on Linux!).

See my article: http://kraksat.pl/en/apc/

Answer (score 1):

I purchased a pair of these modules a few weeks back and sat down to set them up yesterday. This thread really helped to persist in getting them actually working with the RF-Magic software, which wouldn't recognise anything or function in any way for hours until I found the right combination.

For me:

- You must set the adapter to COM1 @ 19200 baud in Windows, it would not work on any other port or at any other speed. If something is using COM1 already, set the adapter to COM1, take it out of the USB socket then reinsert, so Windows clears the COM1 port properly. You can test if the adapter is working in an ordinary terminal program by wiring the TXD and RXD connections together; anything you type will appear in the terminal. If it isn't, try removing and reconnecting a few times.
- You must insert the adapter without the radio unit connected, and wait for it to recognise/initialise. Then, start RF-Magic as Local Administrator plus Compatibility for Windows XP-SP3 turned on (make a shortcut with these properties, saves time if you try this multiple times).
- In RF-Magic, select COM1 (if it isn't already connected). Then, insert/connect the radio module. RF-Magic immediately came up saing "Module detected!" when I did this, I didn't have to hit Read for it to detect.

From there it's straightforward to set it up. Just be aware that RF-Magic lets you use 1200baud as an RF data rate - this isn't supported according to the datasheet, and did not work when I tried it.

### Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

For configuring the APC220 I used this instead of RF Magic:
https://allodox.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/configuring-an-apc220-rf-transceiver-with-arduino/

Workd great, also for Raspberry after translating it to Python.

On PC side I tried to use the RP6v2 Adapter (WT DONGLE). It only worked with pin 1 (SET) of the APC220 module disconnected  - not for configuring but at least for transmitting and receiving data.